# How to specify a foreign key with code-first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I create a foreign key with Entity Framework code-first?

I need a table post to have a column `userId` as a foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following property attribute `[ForeignKey("Column Name")]`. Typically you would assign a foreign key on a navigational property not the foreign key column.

**Example**

```
public class Employee {
    public int Employee Id { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if i'm inserting an Employee, would inserting a new manager row when the ManagerId is 0 be the expected behaviour? I guess I'll need a FK constraint..

Comment: Entity Framework will recognize the "ManagerId" column as the primary key and define it as an auto-increment primary key field within SQL Server. Check out [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for a complete tutorial on getting started which demonstrates this, and much more, with details.